# Облако тегов как титры у фильма «Звёздные войны». Где взять?

Tags: html

Подскажите, как сделать такое облако тегов, как титры в фильме «Звёздные войны»?

Comment: На HTML — никак.

Comment: @kirelagin я бы не был так категоричен: можно сверстать руками и заполнить облако вручную :)

Comment: @Александр Илянкин Пожалуй, Вам стоит уточнить, что Вы хотите использовать: PHP, Python и т.п.

Comment: woweb, ucoz, freelance и другие похожие сайты в помощь.

Comment: Интересно, а можно ли обойтись здесь только применением js-магии?

Comment: Можно, если не надо делать уход текста в перспективу (т.е. искажения), а просто уменьшение шрифта. Ну и с источником данных будут проблемы: строить теги можно будет только на основании тех данных, что на этой же странице. (считается, что запросить у сервера нельзя).

Comment: @cy6erGn0m ой да ладно! Есть же библиотеки, которые на JS 3д рисуют, уже с перспективой, думаю, проблем не будет. А теги можно брать и с чьего-нибудь другого сервера).

Comment: Тут только JS поможет :))) ...Собственно, в гугл вбей "Облако Тегов".
Увидишь ответ на свой вопрос ))) ...Уже есть куча готовых скриптов на эту тему :)

Comment: а почему мой ответ в комментарии перевели?

Comment: @Сергей Ваш ответ переведен в комментарии, потому что он не отвечает на вопрос, а указывает направление дальнейшего поиска.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за пояснение. Сделали бы хоть функцию оповещения о таких действиях.

Comment: @Сергей. Это мысль. Мы обдумаем эту возможность. Но кроме того, мы напишем в блоге о правилах, которыми мы руководствуемся, когда правим или удаляем сообщения, переводим их в комментарии и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

[Без Яваскрипта](http://blog.gesteves.com/post/261593774/im-done-star-wars-opening-crawl-using-only-html) пока только в Сафари. А вариантов с JS в гугле завались. Например: [1](http://acko.net/files/projective/index.html) и [2](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html). Правда у всех код довольно немаленький.